# Navigate sliding form with Tab Key in addition to mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, navigation

I am getting a headache! I've been working on this code for hours now, and I have no idea why it's not working. I have a form that is broken up into parts, and when one part is complete, the user can click on the next tab in the navigation bar to advance to the next part of the form. The next part slides in and the user can continue with the form. This works just fine when using the mouse click as the action of the function, however, if the user is using the "Tab" key to navigate, the sliding form does not slide in correctly and completely. I'm left with a portion of the previous part of the form still in view, along with the current part of the form. This is the code I have so far that works for the mouse click:

```
$('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){
    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;
    $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $this.parent().addClass('selected');
    /*
    we store the position of the link
    in the current variable 
    */
    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
    /*
    animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding
    fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation
    is the order of the fieldsets.
    Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first 
    input element of the new fieldset
    If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate
    all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one
    before the form slided
    */
    $('#steps').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + widths[current-1] + 'px'
    },500,function(){
        if(current == fieldsetCount)
            validateSteps();
        else
            validateStep(prev);
        $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(current) +')').find(':input:first').focus();    
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now when I try to make it work for the "Tab" key I use this code (and\or variations of this code), but nothing seems to work:

```
$('#navigation a').bind('keypress',function(e){
    var $this   = $(this);
    var prev    = current;
    $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $this.parent().addClass('selected');
    /*
    we store the position of the link
    in the current variable 
    */
    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;

    var $fieldset = $(this);
    $fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keypress(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 9){
            $('#steps').stop().animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + widths[current-1] + 'px'
    },500,function(){
        if(current == fieldsetCount)
            validateSteps();
        else
            validateStep(prev);
        $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(current) +')').find(':input:first').focus();    
    });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

You can see how it's working and not working over at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GTmwU/13/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2Fbrt/

Couple of things here. I've change what you are binding the event to. For some reason you had added it to the navigation, so it never fired. I've changed that a bit so it is bound to the last input (only - not select) of each fieldset. I've also used `keydown` instead of `keypress`.

Be aware that you have disabled shift tabbing entirely, I would recommend adding in another binding to figure out which direction you are going in. In fact, there is a simpler way of achieving this which binds to more places but is otherwise less intrusive. I'm not recommending this here as I don't know the scope of your form. Let me know if you are interested!

Hope this helps and just drop a comment if I've made any errors or left something unclear.

Comment: @Inrbob Thanks! I was trying to use the same code structure that I had used to get the mouse click to work, but apparently that didn't work! So, to create a binding method to utilize the shift+tab method to move backward, would I just need to use mostly the same code just change the condition in the id statement and the direction that the slide happens? I'd be interested to know of the alternate way that you know of to bind the keys to events. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. The alternative method I've used before is to have a focus  listener bound to each input. Then when it fires there is a simple if to see whether the current area is visible and, if not, slide the correct area in. I started a quick mock-up but I think there may be a lot of changes required due to your current setup. The problem being when you give focus to a element it will jump into view. I normally hide inactive elements with `display:none` or some-such